# convert response in pdf MULE

Tags: http, pdf, mule

I need help for reaching my object's task target. I have got a BufferInputStream in a http component response and i need to convert these object in a pdf file. Can someone help me using component "File"? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The HTTP Listener and Requester both will return an InputStrem...That InputStream will need to be read and converted into whatever is required downstream.

What is being received in that InputStream?

BTW - If the InputStream does not contain the PDF binary then you will need to use a third-party lib to assemble your data into a PDF format.

Comment: I resolve for inputstream but the generated pdf contains 42 blank pages(if i open it with sublime text, file is filled)